# Playing a Sound at a Specified Time During a CountDown Timer (before it finishes)?

Tags: android, audio, timer, mp3

I would like to tell the Home Activity to play a mp3 sound when there is 20 minutes left in the CountDown Timer and being relatively new at Eclipse I just can't figure it out, everything I have tried just doesn't work.

```
public class Home extends Activity {
Button btnStart;
TextView textViewTime;
MediaPlayer mpAudio;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);



        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        textViewTime  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        textViewTime.setText("01:00:00"); 

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(3600000,1000);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }


        });


    }

public void tipsandtricks(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TipsandtricksActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void about(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}


public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer  {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTime.setText("Free Transfer Over");
            playSound();
        }

        public void playSound() {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), (R.raw.freetransferover));
            mp.start();

        }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

          long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);

            textViewTime.setText(hms);
    {

    if((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished)==20) &&
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))==00)

    {

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(7000);

    {   

    }


    }

    }
    }






}
```

}

As you can see in the code (which functions correctly) I've gotten an mp3 sound to play when the CountDown Timer finishes and I figured out how to get the Vibrator to work when there is 20 minutes left. But how to I get a second mp3 sound to play only once when the CountDown Timer hits 20 minutes left?

Any help is greatly appreciated.